# HQL query, how to?

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am working query with little idea of what software I am dealing with and minimum knowledge HQL.

What I am looking is,

```
SELECT Entity1 FROM Entity AS Entity1
WHERE (EXISTS ELEMENTS(Entity1.config.dateTimeInfo.ntpConfig.server) )
```

But I want to set a condition saying

```
WHERE count(ELEMENTS(Entity1.config.dateTimeInfo.ntpConfig.server) > 3)
```

Can any one please tell me how to achaive it?

Regards,
 sam

Comment: Please reformat your question. Code snippets should be inside a code block.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to select rows based on the size of a collection, which should be:

```
WHERE size(Entity1.config.dateTimeInfo.ntpConfig.server) > 3
```

For more info, check out the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions).